# skip hidden folders in a loop in Windows bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file to execute a block of actions recursively in all the sub-folders of the current directory, but I need to skip the hidden folders, I have started with this:

```
echo off
set back=%cd%

for /r "C:\Temp\" %%i in (.) do (
cd "%%i"

echo 'Current directory:'
echo %%i
dir
cd ..
pause
)
cd %back%
```

But I have no idea how to skip empty folders, can you please help me?

Comment: I suggest to use `PushD/PopD` instead of cd. Also use a `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B /S /AD-H-S "C:\Temp\" 2^>Nul') do (...`

Comment: very good but it fails for folders like ".git" do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I've no problems listing folders with a leading dot, is `.git` probaply hidden? Use `attrib /D ".*"` to check.

Comment: No I mean that .git should be skipped... can I skip also all the folders starting with “.”

Comment: Instead of using `For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/AD-H "C:\Temp" 2^>Nul')Do…`, you could also try, `For /D /R "C:\Temp" %%A In (*)Do…`, but if you intend to use filter those results, the latter becomes less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

- use `dir` instead of `for /r` which has no option to skip Hidden or System files/folders.
- use PushD/PopD to change directory and jump back
- to skip folders pipe to a find/findstr /V

---

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('
  dir /B /S /AD-H-S "C:\temp\" 2^>Nul ^| findstr /V "^\. \\\."
') do (
    PushD "%%i"
    echo 'Current directory:'
    cd
    dir
    PopD
    pause
)
```

Here `findstr /V "^\. \\\."` uses `/V` to exclude matched lines in default RegEx mode and

`"^\. \\\."` matches either a literal dot at line begin or after a backslash.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you ;)